# Reverse iterator is being advanced by std::set::erase

Tags: c++11, stdset

I am trying to erase the element that I just traversed into. I initially forgot to store the return value of s1.erase(...  inside the for loop to ultimately set the condition to exit the loop. With the way the code is right now, I expected the loop to continue indefinitely. But it works just the way it was originally intended to work.
It looks like std::erase advances the iterator and stores the value in rit. I am not able to find any documentation that explains this behavior.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase says that the iterator returned has to be stored. All arguments of the set::erase are passed by value, so how is the reverse iterator being advanced?

How is this loop completing?

```
std::set<int> s1;
s1.insert(20);
s1.insert(30);
s1.insert(50);

auto rit = s1.rbegin();

for (; rit!= s1.rend();)
{
    std::cout << "rit is " << *rit << " size is " << s1.size() << std::endl;
    s1.erase(std::next(rit).base());
    std::cout << "rit after erase is " << *rit << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

rit is 50 size is 3

rit after erase is 30

rit is 30 size is 2

rit after erase is 20

rit is 20 size is 1

Segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that `reverse_iterator::base()` is always one element behind the apparent iterator's value. For example, after `auto rit = s1.rbegin()`, `*rit` returns the last element, while `rit.base() == s1.end()`.

In other words, `*rit == *prev(rit.base())`

In your loop, initially `rit.base() == s1.end()`. Then `std::next(rit).base()` refers to the last element; that element is being erased. In `std::set`, erasing an element only invalidates iterators to that element, but not any others. `s1.end()` is still a valid iterator, and so is `rit`, with `rit.base()` still equal to `s1.end()`. So on the next iteration of the loop, you erase the last element again, and leave `rit.base() == s1.end()` again. And so on.

At some point, the last element is erased, `s1` becomes empty, and then `*rit` exhibits undefined behavior. Recall that `*rit == *prev(rit.base())`, but there is no previous element anymore.